# How to add a hyperlink column in the devexpress ASPxGridView control?

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to add to my GridView from Devexpress ( c# asp.net ) a hyperlink column where i want to set the name of each row to the value of the data.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: What have you tried so far as I know for sure there is an example on the devexpress website, which makes me think you are just looking for someone to do everything for you.

Comment: @user532104 take a look at here http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E308.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "set the name of each row?" You mean the text displayed on the hyperlink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [ASPxGridView documentation](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E308.aspx) regarding *How to create and configure a HyperLink column at runtime*:

```
public void PopulateColumns() {
    GridViewDataTextColumn colID = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
    colID.FieldName = "ID";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colID);

    GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn colItemName = new GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn();
    colItemName.FieldName = "ItemName";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.NavigateUrlFormatString ="~/details.aspx?Device={0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextFormatString = "Device {0}";
    colItemName.PropertiesHyperLinkEdit.TextField = "ItemName";
    ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colItemName);
}
```